# How to open PopUp-window at ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jscript

I've prepared js-code to open a window. But when I click to the call-button 
 popup window doesn't appear.

Here is my simple JS-code:

```html
function OnGetRowValues(r) {

    pcMeasurementsChoiceMSQQ.SetContentUrl('PageProgress.aspx?Page=~/Passport/FormMSQQ_MI.aspx?pos=' + hfWR.Get("PosID") + ';id_measurement=');
    pcMeasurementsChoiceMSQQ.Show();
}
```

Html-fragment also (with CustomButtonClickEvent and GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton) :

```html
 <ClientSideEvents CustomButtonClick="CustomButtonClickMSQQ" CallbackError="function(s, e) { OnCallbackErr('msgUser', e); }" />
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewCommandColumn Name="CommandButtons" ButtonType="Image" VisibleIndex="0"
                    ShowClearFilterButton="true" ShowEditButton="false" ShowDeleteButton="false"
                    ShowNewButton="false">
                    <CustomButtons>
                        <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="btnInsertMI" Text="Выбрать СИ к Блоку"
                            Image-AlternateText="Добавить СИ к заявке" Image-SpriteProperties-CssClass="spr_folder_add12" />
                    </CustomButtons>
```

Message appeared (ARM_Metrolog/CardFileMSQQ/PageProgress.aspx - Unanable!!!), seems like path is wrong, don't know why?! It's true:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI37o.jpg)

Comment: Is PageProgress.aspx in the same folder as your page?

Comment: Thank you so much! Problem solved.